# Como obtener ciertos registros de una tabla pivote en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

por favor necesito ayuda, soy nuevo en Laravel, ya el desarrollo de los CRUDS todo bien, pero a la hora de querer sacar reportes o información de las tablas no puedo.
Tengo dos tablas (articulos y entradas) con una relación muchos a muchos.
**Tabla articulos**
id
nombre

**Tabla entradas**
id
factura
fecha

**Tabla pivot (articulo_entrada)**
entrada_id
articulo_id
cantidad
precio

**Este es el modelo de la tabla articulos**

```
class Articulo extends Model  
{  
    public $table = 'articulos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function entradas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Entrada::class);
    }
 
}
```

**Este es el modelo de la tabla entradas**

```
class Entrada extends Model  
{  
    public $table = 'entradas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'fecha',
        'factura',
        'proveedor_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];


    public function articulos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Articulo::class)->withPivot('cantidad', 'precio');
    }
  
}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener los registros de la tabla pivot "articulo_entrada" que por ejemplo articulo_id = 1 o a x articulo.
**En mi controlador de articulos tengo**

```
public function entradasxarticulo()  
{  
     $entradas = Articulo::find(1)->entradas()->where('articulo_id', '1')->get();  

     //dd($entradas);  

     return view('admin.entradas.entradasxarticulo', compact('entradas'));  
}
```

Esto no da error, pero me manda todos los registros de la tabla pivot "articulo_entrada"

¿Como obtengo de la tabla pivot solo aquellos registros de x articulo, es decir articulo_id de la tabla pivot igual a x id de la tabla artículos?

Comment: Para obtener las entradas del articulo 1 puedes hacer `$entradas = Articulo::find(1)->entradas` no es necesario el where, ya que se entiende que las entradas serán las que estén relacionadas a ese artículo

Comment: @porloscerros considera publicar tu solución

Comment: @BetaM ahí publiqué una respuesta con lo que comentaba. Me incliné hacia eloquent también, no incluí la opción con query builder `$filas = DB::table('articulo_entrada')->where('articulo_id', $x)->get();`. ¿Te parece que query builder también podría responder la pregunta?

Comment: Yo lo dejaría a nivel de Eloquent @porloscerros pues es lo que expone usar el OP, aunque claro que también la otra ayuda

Comment: Muchísmas gracias por contestar y ayudar, lo voy a intentar, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: buenas tardes yo tengo el mismo problema todo me genera bien pero no me retorna la informacion extra de la tabla pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes comenzar la consulta desde uno de los modelos, típicamente del que tienes la id guardada en `$x`.

Entonces, para obtener las Entradas del Articulo `$x`, puedes hacer:

```
$entradas = Articulo::find($x)->entradas;
```

De esa forma, haces una consulta para obtener el Artículo, y por [*lazy loading*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) consultas las entradas relacionadas.

O puedes consultar la relación usando [eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$articulo = Articulo::with('entradas')->find($x); 
$entradas = $articulo->entradas;
```

De la consulta obtendrás un objeto `Articulo`, con la relación `entradas` en uno de sus atributos, donde habrá una colección de objetos `Entrada`, y en cada entrada, anidado un campo `pivot` con los datos de la tabla `pivot`.
O sea, en blade podrías iterar sobre la colección de entradas y acceder a los valores de la tabla `articulo_entrada` a través del atributo `pivot`:

```
@foreach($entradas as $entrada)
    <p>factura: {{ $entrada->factura }}</p>
    <p>fecha entrada: {{ $entrada->fecha }}</p>

    <p>cantidad: {{ $entrada->pivot->cantidad }}</p>
    <p>precio: {{ $entrada->pivot->precio }}</p>
@endforeach
```

O si le pasas directamente el artículo a la vista:

```
return view('admin.entradas.entradasxarticulo', compact('articulo'));
```

podrías iterar sobre la relación:

```
<h3>{{ $articulo->nombre }}</h3>
@foreach($articulo->entradas as $entrada)
    <p>factura: {{ $entrada->factura }}</p>
    <p>fecha entrada: {{ $entrada->fecha }}</p>

    <p>cantidad: {{ $entrada->pivot->cantidad }}</p>
    <p>precio: {{ $entrada->pivot->precio }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Sólo ten en cuenta que aquí estamos usando la relación `entradas` y para acceder a `cantidad` y `precio` de la tabla `articulo_entrada`, debes agregar en la relación que declaraste en el modelo `Articulo`, el método `withPivot` con las dos columnas extra:

```
public function entradas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Entrada::class)->withPivot('cantidad', 'precio');
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por contestar, estoy trabajando en tu idea, pero no me trae el nombre del artículo. En el controlador:    $entradas = Articulo::find($id)->entradas()->get();

Comment: Se esa manera la consulta solo va a traer las entradas. Para traer el artículo debes hacer `$articulo = Articulo::with('entradas')->find($x); ` y pasarle esa variable a la vista `return view('admin.entradas.entradasxarticulo', compact('articulo')); `

Comment: Hola, disculpa la molestia, usé Articulo::with('entradas´)->find($id); y ahora me da el siguiente error en el blade.php  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() en el blade.php le puse @foreach($articulo->entradas as $entrada) es la línea donde marca el error, gracias por tu atención.

Comment: @Omar, así debería funcionar. Posiblemente tengas algún error. Por favor agrega en la pregunta, debajo del original, cómo quedó tu código. También sería útil un dump de los resultados de la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Yo modificaría tu consulta de está forma:

```
Artículo::with(['entradas' =>  function($query) {
    $query->whereArticuloId(1);
}])->get();
```

- Hacemos una carga ambiciosa de las relaciones de **`entradas`**
- Filtramos estableciendo de forma interna una consulta donde usamos un **`where`**

Ahora para pasar un valor dinámico por medio de una variable como está:

```
$id = 2;
```

Y luego lo usas en tu consulta así:

```
Artículo::with(['entradas' =>  function($query) use($id) {
    $query->whereArticuloId($id);
}])->get();
```

Te grego info extra, esta consulta filtraría por aquellas entradas cuyo `articulo_id` sea igual a 1 pero también traería aquellos artículos que incluso no tienen al menos una relación con alguna entrada.

Para solventar lo anterior, yo haría uso del [método `has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Artículo::has('entradas')->with(['entradas' =>  function($query) use($id) {
    $query->whereArticuloId($id);
}])->get();
```

Obteniendo una salida con una estructura similar a esta:

```
{
    objeto 1
    "relacion": [
                {
                    objeto 1
                },
                {
                    objeto 2
                }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Aunque como opinión **yo me quedaría con la respuesta de @porloscerrosΨ** mas simple

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, estoy trabajando en ver cual es la mejor opción, de antemano gracias.